# Add URL variables with Server.Transfer in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently trying to add a variable to the url using Server.Transfer. I need to use Server.Transfer as I need to keep form post data which is why I can't use Response.Redirect.

I am using `Server.Transfer("add_account.aspx?error=userNotFound");` but the variable is not being added to the URL.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually with Server.Transfer, we use context to pass data around:

```
Context.Items["error"] = "UserNotFound";
Server.Transfer("add_account.aspx");
```

This is a state container like Session and Application, but it only persists for the current request and then goes away.